# Proof that $(A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \subset (A \cup C) \times (B \cup D)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried as follows, please tell me what to do next. 
Let $(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \implies (x,y) \in (A \times B)$  or $ (x,y) \in (C \times D)
\implies ( x \in A$ and $y \in B )$ or $ ( x \in C$  and $y \in D )$

Or, if any other methods to proof the above problem.

Comment: You are practically there. If $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, is $(x,y)\in (A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)$? For that to hold, you need $x\in A\cup C$ and $y\in B\cup D$. Does that hold under the assumption? And then deal with the other case.

Comment: Actually you can say $(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \Leftrightarrow( x \in A$ and $y \in B )$ or $ ( x \in C$  and $y \in D )$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Think about why this is a tautology:$$\forall_{(x,y)}(\underset{\text{This is what you get so far}}{\underline{((x\in A ∧ y\in B) ∨ (x\in C ∧ y\in D))}} \Rightarrow \underset{\text{This is how do we translate the rest}}{\underline{((x\in A ∨x\in C) ∧ (y\in B ∨y\in D))}})$$
Here is the [Truth table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Truth+table%28A+and+B%29or%28C+and+D%29implies%28A+or+C%29and%28B+or+D%29).

**Answer:**

> Let $(x,y)$ be arbitrary ordered pair we have:\begin{align}&(x\in A ∧ y\in B) ∨ (x\in C ∧ y\in D)\\\equiv&(((x\in A ∧ y\in B) ∨x\in C) ∧ ((x\in A ∧ y\in B) ∨y\in D))\hspace{7ex}\text{Distributive law}\times 2\\\equiv&(\color{red}{(x\in A∨x\in C)} ∧ (y\in B∨x\in C)) ∧ ((x\in A∨y\in D) ∧ \color{orange}{(y\in B∨y\in D)})\\\Rightarrow&\color{red}{(x\in A ∨x\in C)} ∧ \color{orange}{(y\in B ∨y\in D)}\hspace{2ex}\text{Associative & Commutative & Conjunction Elim}\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost done. In any case, $x\in A\cup C$ and $y\in B\cup D$. That is, $(x,y)\in (A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)$.

Comment: But, the issue is, it makes both sides equal. But, I have to show a subset relationship.

Comment: No, it doesn't make them equal, in general. We showed that if $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cup (C\times D)$ THEN $(x,y)\in (A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)$. We haven't showed the opposite, that in fact is not true. Take for example $A=D=\{1\}$ and $B=C=\emptyset$. Then we have $(A\times B)\cup (C\times D)=\emptyset$ but $(A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)=(1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks again. 

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, then $x \in A\cup C$ and $y \in B \cup D$ thus $(x,y) \in (A\cup C) \times (B \cup D)$ 
The same for the orher case

Comment: Ok. But, why I need to put a subset symbol instead of equal ?